# Печатать горизонтально в консоли

Tags: javascript

Как печатать строку в консоли горизонтально? Например, в Java-е есть `System.out.print()`, позволяющий печатать строку по горизонтали, и  `System.out.println()` - по вертикали. Есть такая возможность в JS?
Например, хочу печатать это:

```
*
**
***
****
```

с этим кодом не получается:

```js
for (let i = 0; i <=4; i++) {
    for (let k = 0; k < i; k++) {
        console.log('*')
    }
    console.log(' ')
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
for (let i = 0; i <= 4; i++) {
  let str = '';
  for (let k = 0; k <= i; k++) {
    str += '*'
  }
  console.log(str);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Если речь про браузер, то такой возможности нет.

Если про nodejs, то есть:

```
for (var q=0; q<10; ++q) {
  process.stdout.write("" + q)
}
```